# Forgotten Gmail address used to login into Blogger

Tags: blogger

My friend has a Blogspot blog which he managed trough Blogger.

He knows the URL to the blog, the password he used to log in, but not the Gmail address.

Is there any way he can retrieve his account?

Comment: Can't he just try his few (?) mail accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, unfortunately there is no way that you could get back your blog on Blogger if your don't remember the login ID/email.

Read more:

- [Blogger Accounts, Email Addresses, And Google Accounts](http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2009/08/your-email-address-and-blogger-account.html)
- [Why Can't Blogger Just Tell Me The Email Address, When I Ask For It?](http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2011/12/why-cant-blogger-just-tell-us-email.html)
- [Recovering Your Account Information](http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2010/04/recovering-your-account-information.html)